# Passing parameters into KSOAP2

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

Thank you in advance for taking a moment to read this question. I am trying to integrate an android app with a SOAP webservice using ksoap2.

Here is an example request that I am looking to make:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns="http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5_1">
           <soapenv:Header/>
           <soapenv:Body>
             <ValidateStaffLogin>
               <Request>
                 <SourceCredentials>
                   <SourceName>JohnDoe</SourceName>
                   <Password>123ABCFAKEAPIKEY123</Password>
                   <SiteIDs>
                     <int>-99</int>
                   </SiteIDs>
                 </SourceCredentials>
                 <Username>Siteowner</Username>
                 <Password>apitest1234</Password>
               </Request>
             </ValidateStaffLogin>
           </soapenv:Body>
         </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is a snippet of the webservice java file:

```
public class WebService {
//Namespace of the Webservice - can be found in WSDL
private static String NAMESPACE = 
    "http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5_1";
//Webservice URL - WSDL File location
private static String URL = 
    "https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5_1/StaffService.asmx";
//SOAP Action URI again Namespace + Web method name
private static String SOAP_ACTION = 
    "http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5_1";

public static boolean invokeLoginWS(String userName,String passWord, String 
webMethName) {
    boolean loginStatus = false;
    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, webMethName);

    request.addProperty("SourceCredentials", "SourceName", "JohnDoe");
    request.addProperty("SourceCredentials", "Password", 
        "123ABCFAKEAPIKEY123");
    request.addProperty("SourceCredentials", "SiteIDs", "-99");
    request.addProperty("Username", "Siteowner");
    request.addProperty("Password", "apitest1234");


    // Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+webMethName, envelope);
        // Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        // Assign it to  boolean variable variable
        loginStatus = Boolean.parseBoolean(response.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
        LoginActivity.errored = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Return booleam to calling object
    return loginStatus;
}
}
```

My question is how exactly am I supposed to pass a different variable into two separate Password fields. I found the ksoap2 method addProperty(namespace, name, value), but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Also I'm slightly confused about the NAMESPACE, URL and SOAP_ACTION variables and how to correctly fill them out.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(ApiUrl.NAMESPACE,
            ApiUrl.METHODNAME_LOGIN);

SoapSerializationEnvelope soapenvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapenvelope.dotNet = true;
    soapenvelope.bodyIn = false;

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
            ApiUrl.DMATURL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
soapenvelope.setAddAdornments(false);
    androidHttpTransport
            .setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    // HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(ApiUrl.SOAPACTION_LOGIN, soapenvelope);
        String responss = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;

        //System.out.println("request==" +androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
    //  System.out.println("responss===" + responss);

        SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) soapenvelope
                .getResponse();
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject) soapenvelope.bodyIn;
}
                catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();   
                }
```